# Bash: change a line in a file iteratively and read pass file.txt to a program

Tags: java, bash, command-line, sed

I try to make this very simple bash program that must make the following operations:

**1)** modify a file java n times: every time i must change a single word in a single line of the file (the line is 11) i know there is the following command that replace a single word in a particular line of a program wih another one:

```
 sed -i "11s/1/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
```

if i do the above command i can modify only one time the file.java because in the second iteration of the for cycle i have not the same word as in the first iteration: i start with 1 in line 11, than in the fist iteration i change with `$n` (that is equal to 2), but now **HOW** i can modify the `sed` command to change again the word (that is now equal to 2) to have, for example, 3 in the 11th line?

2) compile the file java: it's ok;

3) modify a file.txt: again the same problem as in 1) i want to change a word in a line iteratively with a for cycle or something like that;

**4)** pass it to an executable file: this is the second problem. I have  modify the param.txt file and now i want to read it into an executable file called **exec**. If i do this from the terminal i must launch the exec. program with the command `./exec` and after that i must write from screen the file.txt name. Now is it possible to launch a program from bash and  read with it the file.txt? I try with:

```
 sed -i "13s/Zero/$n/" param.txt
 ./exec < param.txt
```

that script must change the line 13 from Zero to $n in param.txt **how** i can launch the exec program with the command `./exec` with the specific param.txt file.

```
#!/bin/bash

n=0
for n in "2" "3" 
do
  sed -i "11s/1/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
  javac IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java  
  java IC_masslessPlanetesimal
 sed -i "13s/Zero/$n/" param.txt
 ./exec < param.txt   
done
```

thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Ad 4: Does _i must write from screen the file.txt name_ mean that you have to type the name of the text file as input followed by ENTER?

Comment: 1. Avoid multiple questions in one post. 2. Instead of substituting a specfic number, you can specify a pattern as per your needs, e.g. _[0-9]+_

Comment: @ halfbit yes, i must do this for the program to make readable the file.txt for the ./exec

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to keep track of previous n value. It will cover first 3 points.

```
#!/bin/bash
n=0
prev=1
for n in "2" "3"
do
  sed -i "11s/$prev/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java

  javac IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java  
  java IC_masslessPlanetesimal
  sed -i "13s/Zero/$prev/" param.txt
  echo "param.txt" | ./exec   
  prev=$n
done
```

Comment: Yes this solve the first three point of my question thanks a lot it was easier than I thought. For the last question i really do not understand how to pass the file.txt to the program.

Comment: Not sure how your exec works. You can try this
    echo "param.txt" | ./exec

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem in a very simple (but not so formal way):

i go to the file.f90 and re-define it so i change the shell commands to file.txt that the file must read when it compile.

Now the bash is very simple:

```
 #!/bin/bash


    touch IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
    touch param.in

m=1
n=0
for n in  "2" "3" 
do
 sed -i "11s/$m/$n/" IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java
 javac IC_masslessPlanetesimal.java  
 java IC_masslessPlanetesimal
 sed -i "13s/$m/$n/" param.in 
 ./swifter_symba_omp # now i just launch the modify version of ./exec that read the files in which i declare the input to the ./exec
 m=$n
done
```

Thanks a lot for your answers comments and tips.